# Automapper not properly mapping child collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm seeing different behavior mapping `TypeView` -> `Type` when I map the types directly, vs when that type is used in another type.

In this example I want to map from the `View` types into the non-`View` types:

```
    //db model
    public class TestClass
    {
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public List<ChildClass> ChildClasses { get; set; }
    }
    public class ChildClass
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    }

    //view model from client
    public class TestClassView
    {        
public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public List<ChildClassView> ChildClasses { get; set; }
    }
    public class ChildClassView
    {
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    }
```

In this case I don't want `CreateDate` to be settable by the view, as it is a generated field. So define my mapping profiles to ignore it on both the parent and child views:

```
    CreateMap<TestClassView, TestClass>()
        .ForMember(x => x.CreateDate, config => config.Ignore())
        ;
    CreateMap<ChildClassView, ChildClass>()
        .EqualityComparison((m, v) => m.Id == v.Id)
        .ForMember(x => x.CreateDate, config => config.Ignore())
        ;

    //automapper configuration
        services.AddAutoMapper(c =>
        {
            c.AddCollectionMappers();
        },typeof(TestClassProfile).Assembly);
```

So now I write a unit test to verify that the `CreateDate` is ignored, but I get different results for the `ChildClass.CreateDate` when I map directly from `ChildClassView` -> `ChildClass` than when I map the `TestClassView` -> `TestClass`.

This test passes:

```
    var target1 = new ChildClass
    {
        CreateDate = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1)
    };
    var source1 = new ChildClassView
    {
        // no create date set
    };
    Mapper.Map(source1, target1);

    //works
    target1.CreateDate.Should().Be(new DateTime(2022, 1, 1));
```

This does not:

```
    var target2 = new TestClass
    {
        ChildClasses = new()
        {
            new ChildClass
            {
                Id = 1,
                CreateDate = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1)
            }
        }
    };
    var source2 = new TestClassView
    {
        ChildClasses = new()
        {
            new ChildClassView
            {
                Id = 1,
                // no create date set
            }
        }
    };

    Mapper.Map(source2, target2);

    //doesn't work. CreateDate is DateTime.MinValue.
    target2.ChildClasses.First().CreateDate.Should().Be(new DateTime(2022, 1, 1));
```

Why does it seem like Automapper is ignoring my config value in the second example? How do I get it to respect the mapping for my child class when mapping the parent class? I tried to explictly state where the mapping for `ChildClasses` should come from, but got the same result.

I tried making `ChildClass` as a singular property under `TestClass`, and that properly mapped. It's only when mapping a collection that it's wrong.

UPDATE: I tried using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747877/automapper-usedestinationvalue-does-not-work-for-collections) as suggested in the comments, but i'm still getting the same result. See above where I added the AddCollectionMappers() and the EqualityComparison specification to my child type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automapper: UseDestinationValue does not work for collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747877/automapper-usedestinationvalue-does-not-work-for-collections)

Comment: @Progman I now see why my code wouldn't work as is, but following the steps in the linked question I'm still getting the same issue, even with specifying the equality comparison and giving my test objects matching IDs